# Objects are becoming obsolete after reopening the application

Tags: wpf, qtp, hp-uft, uft14

After finishing up writing my tests, everything is working fine, but once I reopen (or restarts my PC) my application / restarts the PC then the test won't work, UFT won't identify any object expect a selected few and I have to re-assign everything (remove them from the object repository, and read them with the same name)
note - after reopening - the spy won't find the objects.

I am trying to test a WPF application

Comment: Please add some more information, for example what properties is the Object Repository using to identify these objects.

Comment: He identified them through the object spy

Comment: The Object Repository lists the properties used to identify the object, after restarting the application you can compare these properties with those the Spy shows in order to see what has changed and why the object is no longer identified.

Comment: As @Motti said, please add more information. You may want to attach the screenshot of object repository. There may be dynamic property values causing issues.

Comment: I've tried to compare them, the properties are the same, the application is the same, but it still happens

Comment: @AnkurJain everything is static, nothing is being changed.

Comment: @IdoHLevi ok, see if one of these 21 tips help you https://www.learnqtp.com/uft-object-identification-tips/